# Inserting user data with stored procedure gives error when committing

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pyodbc

This code gives an error on `conn.commit` line.

```
Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now (2014) (SQLEndTran)")
```

Whenever I call SP the ID is keep increasing in table but record is not inserting.

```
@app.route("/insert_user")
def insert_user():        
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc3.so};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=user_data;USER=user;PASSWORD=user_pass;OPTION=3;autoCommit = True")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("{call insert_user_sp(0,'aby@gmail.com','345','male','1992-01-12','www.facebook.com','abc','xyz','p','jr','english','i am student')}")
        conn.commit()

    except Error as e:
        print e

    finally:
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `cur.commit()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using MySQL on Linux, I would recommend using a MySQL Python package rather than `pyodbc`. I use `pyodbc` for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server, but this package when using MySQL:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient

Then you can use `cursor.callproc()`:

http://mysqlclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html?highlight=callproc#cursor-objects

Good luck!

Comment: Does mysqlclient offer significant advantages over MySQL Connector/Python, or is it simply a matter of personal preference? (Just curious. I've used MySQL Connector/Python a few times and had no complaints, but I wasn't doing anything fancy.)

Comment: It supports Python 2 and 3 and is actively maintained. I recommend it because Django does here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers